# Error on adding <script> to master page

Tags: asp.net, webforms, master-pages

I have a Master page that have these `ContentPlaceHolder`:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="title" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="contentTitle" runat="server" ></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="content" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

when I add these codes for jquery in`<head>` part of master page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-2.0.1.min.js" />
<link href="script/jquery.contextMenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.contextMenu.js" />
```

and create new aspx file that use that master page ;

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Default.Master"    AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Bed.aspx.cs" Inherits="Zhotel.Lists.Bed" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="title" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="contentTitle" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="content" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

when I want to view Design part of file it show me this error:

[image]

and when I remove `script` tags then no more this error occurs.

How can I use `script` tag that this error not shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `</script>` to end of jquery definition, like this:

```
<script src="script/jquery-2.0.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="script/jquery.contextMenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

place your scripts outside of contentplaceholder 'title' in head section and make sure that your page has correct reference to your masterpage and also make sure that you are placing the contentplaceholders in their appropriate places

Comment: the OP seems to have found the answer.