# Adding jQuery to all pages of web application

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms, scriptmanager

How can I add the jQuery file for use in all pages of the web application?

I tried it [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17010556/2040375) and also using the `ScriptManger` as this in master page's `Page_Load` event:

```
ScriptManager manager = new ScriptManager();
manager.Scripts.Add(new ScriptReference("script/jquery-2.0.1.min.js"));
manager.Scripts.Add(new ScriptReference("script/jquery.contextMenu.js"));
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it declaratively in the master page by dragging the files from Solution Explorer window to the code view of the mark-up.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it in the master page file.

When placing it in the master page, it applies to all pages that use the master page.

Answer (score 0):

Add your script to the master page head section, like:

```
<script src="<%=Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/scrpits/jquery1.7.js") %>" />
```